# cumulative sum before, cum sum after

Tags: sql, postgresql

table_1

```
customer_id         month          subscription_price
1               April    2020         49.0
1               May      2020         49.0
1               June     2020         49.0
1               July     2020         49.0
1               February 2021         29.0
1               March    2021         29.0
1               April    2021         29.0
2               January  2020         15.0
2               February 2020         15.0
2               February 2021         30.0
```

Based on the table_1 above, I would like to transform the table into table_2:

```
     c_id     month          before  current after cum_sum_before     cum_sum_after
0       1   April    2020   NaN     49.0    49.0        NaN         49+49+49+NaN+29+29+NaN
1       1   May      2020   49.0    49.0    49.0         49            49+49+NaN+29+29+NaN 
2       1   June     2020   49.0    49.0    49.0       49+49              49+NaN+29+29+NaN     
3       1   July     2020   49.0    49.0     NaN       49+49+49              NaN+29+29+NaN
4       1   February 2021   NaN     29.0    29.0       49+49+49                  29+29+NaN
5       1   March    2021   29.0    29.0    29.0     49+49+49+29                    29+NaN
6       1   April    2021   29.0    29.0     NaN    49+49+49+29+29                     NaN
```

(The additions are just for explanation purpose, I would expect the cum_sum to be integers, not as text).

The query below

```
SELECT customer_id as c_id,month
     ,lag(subscription_price) over (partition by customer_id order by month asc) as before
     ,subscription_price as current
     ,lead(subscription_price) over (partition by customer_id order by month asc) as after
FROM schema.table st
```

transforms table_1 into table_2 with `before, current, after`.
How can I create the columns cumulative sum before and cumulative sum after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want cumulative sums, which looks like:

```
select t.*,
       sum(subscription_price) over (partition by customer_id
                                     order by month
                                     rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                    ) as sum_before,
       sum(subscription_price) over (partition by customer_id
                                     order by month
                                     rows between 1 following and unbounded following
                                    ) as sum_before
from t;
```

Note:  This returns `NULL` for the first and last rows.  To return `0` instead, I often use arithmetic and dispense with the window frame clause:

```
select t.*,
       (sum(subscription_price) over (partition by customer_id
                                      order by month
                                     ) -
        subscription_price
       ) as sum_before,
       (sum(subscription_price) over (partition by customer_id
                                      order by month desc
                                     ) -
        subscription_price
       ) as sum_before
from t;
```

Comment: shouldn't be saying thanks, but many thanks for your 3rd involvement in recent days!

Answer (score 0):

Try using below: (for before)

SELECT
Customer_id, as c_id, month
, sum(Convert(int, Subscription_price)) over (partition by customer_id order by month) as Before
FROM
schema.table st

--You don't need to add ASC for ascending, it automatically assumes that order, however, you need to add DESC if you want to have a descending order.

Let me know if this worked.